# How to find records that have the same range of number of children ( Active Record )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have `Area` model, `User` model look like this:

**Area model:**

```
Nothing!!!
```

**User model:**

```
belongs_to :area, foreign_key: :area_id
```

Now, I can get a number of users of one area by `Area.find(1).users`

But how can I get all areas that have 1 to 10 users, or all areas that have 20 to 30 users?

Comment: Try this and tell me.... `Area.joins(:user).where('user.id = (1..10).to_a)`

Comment: Can you explain your code? I think your code is not true. The areas table doesn't have any columns relate to the users table at all. Only the users table has `area_id` column and that is also the foreign_key to connect to the areas table.

Actually, you cannot use `Area.joins(:user)` here. You can only use `Area.joins("inner join users on users.area_id = areas.id")`. 

And what is the meaning of this `.where('user.id = (1..10).to_a`?

Comment: @PraveshKhatri The above code will just return `Area` records which are associated with users having id 1 to 10

Comment: I believe that is not what @PeterNguyen want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of rails `counter_cache` option

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :area, foreign_key: :area_id, counter_cache: true
end
```

Now create a migration to for area table

```
create :areas do |t|
  t.integer :users_count
  ---- Your other fields---
end
```

Now whenever you associate/remove a `user` with `area` object, rails will itself increase or descrease users_count and store it in `area` object automatically.

You query will be as simple as the following query.

`Area.where(users_count: 1..10)`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of having clause to achieve that

```
Area.joins(:users).group('users.area_id, areas.id').having("COUNT(users.id) BETWEEN 1 and 10")
```

This will generate

```sql
SELECT "areas".* 
FROM "areas" 
INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."area_id" = "areas"."id" 
GROUP BY users.area_id, areas.id 
HAVING count(users.id) between 2 and 10
```

The above code will return the `Area` records where the associated users range between 1 to 10

NOTE: You can change the range according to your requirements

Comment: Thank you, your code is what I need. But I changed my mind, and use @Nimish Gupta's code, because I think the counter_cache method is much cleaner.